Explicit expression for the expected number of up-crossings of Brownian motion
Let $W$ be a standard Brownian motion starting at $1/2$, i.e. $W_0=1/2$. Set
$$\tau := \inf\big\{t>0: W_t\notin (0,1)\big\}.$$
As $(W_t^2-t)_t$ is a martingale, one has $\mathbb P[W_\tau =0]=1/2 = \mathbb P[W_\tau =1]$ and $\mathbb E[\tau]=\mathbb E[W^2_\tau]=1/2$. Denote by $U_t(a,b)$ the number of up-crossings of $W$ through $(a,b)$ up to time $t$.
For $0<a<b<1$, is there an explicit expression for $\mathbb E[U_\tau(a,b)]$? Using Doob's inequality, one has
$$\mathbb E[U_\tau(a,b)]\le \frac{1}{b-a}\mathbb E\big[(a-W_\tau)^+\big]=\frac{a}{2(b-a)}.$$
Is this inequality achieved? It suffices to take (for me) $a=1/2-\epsilon$ and $b=1/2+\epsilon$.
PS : This question is related to Sharpness of Doob's upcrossing inequality

Should I… use even more time on this problem (and related ones)? It is tempting. I have an idea on how to count the upcrossings by expanding the computation i did yesterday in the other post. The fact that it is BM makes it much easier. @Fawen90

I want to say the inequality is not attained in general.

Consider the case $1/2\in(a,b)$ (the other cases should be done similarly). Let $U:=U_\tau(a,b)$.
Then $U\ge1$ means just that $W$ reaches $a$ before $1$ and then reaches $b$ before $0$. So,
$$P(U\ge1)=\frac{1-1/2}{1-a}\frac ab.$$
(This follows from the well-known fact that, for a standard Brownian motion $B$ starting at $0$ and positive real $c$ and $d$, the probability that $B$ will reach $d$ before $-c$ is $\frac c{c+d}$ -- see e.g. Corollary 5.11, taking also into account the strong Markov property of the Brownian motion -- see e.g. Theorem 5.13.)
Similarly,
$$P(U\ge k)=\frac{1-1/2}{1-a}\frac ab\Big(\frac{1-b}{1-a}\frac ab\Big)^{k-1}$$
for $k=1,2,\dots$.
So,
$$EU=\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(U\ge k)=\frac{a/2}{b-a}.$$
So, the upper bound in the inequality in question is indeed attained.

So nice Iosif! I really love your tricky reasoning. Many thanks

This also provides an example that the upper bound of my previous post is attained by non constant martingale
